# passing default values from outer function to repeatedly called inner function in R

Tags: r

> This question differs from my original; it adheres more to a *minimal* reproducible example and incorporates a recommendation by be_green against silently loading entire libraries within the context of a function.

The outer function starts by defining a number of cases, default values, and a list of any case exceptions. The inner function assembles each case by using the default values in a computation unless exceptions are defined. Finally, the outer function assembles these cases into a data frame.

Here is the function:

```
outerfun <- function(cases, var_default, exceptions=list()){
  # Inner Function to create a case
  innerfun <- function(var=var_default) {  # Case
    result = var
    return(result)
  }
  # Combine Cases
  datlist <- list()
  for(case in 1:cases){
    datlist[[paste0("X",case)]] <- do.call(innerfun, as.list(exceptions[[paste0("X",case)]]))
  }
  casedata <- do.call(dplyr::data_frame, datlist)
  return(casedata)
}
```

This function works fine when I define values for the inner function as exceptions:

```
data <- outerfun(cases = 3, var_default = 10, exceptions = list("X2" = c(var = 14)))
```

But not when I mix the two:

```
data <- outerfun(cases = 3, var_default = 10, exceptions = 
                  list("X2"  = c(var = var_default + 4)))
```

Being able to mix the two are important since it makes the function more intuitive and easier to program for a variety of cases.

I think the problem might result from using do.call and have seen other threads detailing this issue (having to do with environments and frames), but I haven't been able to find an optimal solution for me. I like do.call since I can pass a list of arguments into a function. I could turn the inner function into a list (think: function(...) { }) but then I would have to define every variable instead of relying on the default.

Any help or suggestions you might have would be great.

Comment: Please provide a *minimal* reproducible example.  Use this for reference: [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: I'd note quickly that calling require within a function is generally bad practice. It is better to refer to the functions from other package directly with the `::` operator

Comment: I'm still unclear on what the issue is--all the code works just fine for me? I'm seconding @NathanWerth's call for a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @NathanWerth, thank you for the guidance, I'll do my best to create a _minimal_ reproducible example. This is actually a stripped version of a much larger function that I've created. The larger function captures meta data about the parameters used to create each signal and has added parameters for exception periods and outage periods.

Comment: @NathanWerth I've further simplified the code to better adhere to the _minimal_ reproducible example reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**be_green** did solve this first, but I wanted to follow-up with what I actually did for my project.

As **be_green** pointed out, I couldn't call `var_default` within the exception list since it hadn't yet been defined. I didn't understand this at first since you can actually define the default of an argument to a variable defined within the function itself:

```
addfun <- function(x, y = z + x + 2) { 
           z = 20
           c(x, y)
          }
addfun(x = 20)
```

*[1] 20 42*

This is because function arguments in R [lazily evaluated](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#function-arguments).  I thought this gave me a pass to call the function like this:

```
addfun(x = 10, y = x + z)
```

*Error in addfun(x = 10, y = x + z) : object 'x' not found*

If you remove `x` then it calls an error for `z`. So even though the default to `y` is dependent on `x` and `z`, you can't call the function using `x` or `z`.

**be_green** suggested that I pass arguments in a string and then parse it within the function. But I was afraid that others on my team would find the resulting syntax confusing.

Instead, I used ellipsis (`...`) and evaluated the ellipsis arguments within my function. I did this using this line of code:

```
list2env(eval(substitute(alist(...))), envir = as.environment(-1))
```

Here the `eval(substitute(alist(...)))` pattern is common but results in a named list of arguments. Due to some other features, it becomes more convenient to evaluate the arguments as objects within the function. `list2env(x, envir = as.environment(-1))` accomplishes this with an additional step. Once the argument is called, you need to explicitly evaluate the call. So if I wanted to change my `addfun()` above:

```
addfun <- function(x, ...) { 
           z = 20
           list2env(eval(substitute(alist(...))), 
                      envir = as.environment(-1))
           c(x, eval(y))
          }
addfun(x = 10, y = x + z)
```

This is a trite example: I now need to define `y` even though it's not an argument in the function. But now I can even re-define `z` within the function call:

```
addfun(x = 10, y = z + 2, z = 10)
```

This is all possible because of [non-standard evaluation](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html). There can be trade-offs but in my application of non-standard evaluation, I was able to increase the usability and flexibility of the function while making it more intuitive to use.

Final code:

```
outerfun <- function(caseIDs, var_default, ...){
  list2env(eval(substitute(alist(...))), envir = as.environment(-1))
  # Inner Function to create a case
  innerfun <- function(var=var_default) {  # Case
    result = var
    return(result)
  }
  # Combine Cases
  datlist <- lapply(caseIDs, function(case) {
    do.call(innerfun, eval(get0(case, ifnotfound = list())))
  })
  names(datlist) <- caseIDs
  casedata <- do.call(dplyr::data_frame, datlist)
  return(casedata)
}
```

Now both examples work with full functionality:

```
data <- outerfun(caseIDs = c("X1","X2","X3"), var_default = 10, 
         X2 = list(var = 14))
data <- outerfun(caseIDs = c("X1","X2","X3"), var_default = 10, 
         X2 = list(var = var_default + 4))
```

I hope this helps someone else! Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `lvl_default` is not defined outside the context of the function, and yet you call it as an input to a parameter. Because there is no variable called `lvl_default` in the global environment, when the function tries to evaluate the parameter `exceptions = list(X3 - c(lvl = lvl_default + 10)`, it fails to find a variable to evaluate. You are not able to specify parameters by setting them equal to the names of other unevaluated parameters.

Instead, what I would recommend doing is setting a variable outside the function associated with the value you were hoping to pass into `lvl_default` and then pass it into the function like so:

```
level <- 1000

data <- genCaseData(n_signals = 3, datestart = "2017-07-01T15:00:00", 
        n_cycles = 4, period_default = 10, phase_default = 0, ampl_default = 15, 
        lvl_default = level, exceptions = list(X1= c(lvl=980), 
        X3 = c(lvl = level + 10)))
```

Also as I noted in a comment, I would recommend against silently loading entire libraries within the context of a function. You can end up masking things you didn't mean to, and running into strange errors because the require call doesn't actually throw one if a library is unavailable. Instead I would reference the functions through `pkgname::fncname`.

Comment: I wanted to avoid creating default values at the global environment level since this function will be called multiple times within a testing environment. Thanks for the recommendation against silently loading entire libraries. It isn't something I normally do, however this function is called as part of a larger utilities module supporting multiple scripts. But you are right, I could use the `pkgname::fncname` convention for each function call.

Comment: Another reason to avoid the use of global variables is that this function will be used by other members. If I require that they define global variables, the function is no longer enclosed. I haven't run into a package that requires that I define certain global variables before a function will work. I don't want to force that on the team.

Comment: You don't need to define global variables for the function to work. If you are going to pass a variable into a parameter, the function has to be able to evaluate that variable in the environment a level higher than the function.

Comment: Are you talking about something like: [`force(lvl_default)`](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#lazy-evaluation)? It doesn't work in this case.

Comment: No, I'm saying that you can't create a function, like `z <- function(a, b)` and then write `z(a, a+1)` because `a + 1` doesn't exist in the environment outside the function.

Comment: Then is there a way to parse the variable so that it evaluates later in the function? I've toyed with a few combinations of commands like `eval`, `parse`, `deparse`, `substitute`, etc. but haven't gotten them to work in this context.

Comment: You could always have them pass a string as an argument to the function and then evaluate it later. It is a little ugly but it would make the NSE stuff easier.

Comment: That's fair. I had hoped for a more elegant solution, but I'll take practical. ;)